# How to refresh the changes automatically in IIS after ReactJS project deployed

Tags: reactjs, iis

Hi can anyone please help me, When I gave build reactjs project, How to get IIS(Internet Information Services) site to start up automatically after deployment. My requirement is to display the updated changes without manual refresh.

I made changes from few references.

1. In IIS, on the advanced settings for the Application Pool, "Start Mode" should be set to "AlwaysRunning".
2. In IIS, on the advanced settings for the site, "Preload Enabled" should be set to "true".
3. Open cmd as Administrator, I ran iisreset.

But Nothing is worked for me. Anyone please help me out from this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your description correctly. is your ReactJS project already deployed on IIS and you want IIS to restart automatically after making changes to your ReactJS project?

Comment: Yes my reactjs project is already deployed, I want to see the updated changes in browser automatically, without manual refresh, Is it possible to refresh the web page through IIS.